# How do I interpret the VRP problem in Google OR-Tools (CVRPTW)? / where am i going wrong?

Tags: python, python-3.x, optimization, or-tools, vehicle-routing

I am very new to Google OR-Tools. I recently implemented a solution but I am not getting the results that I want.

- I have a time_matrix of size 3900 x 3900 in minutes

  - ```
       [12,  0, 52, ..., 40, 22, 22],
       [55, 50,  0, ..., 65, 39, 39],
       ...,
       [41, 40, 66, ...,  0, 36, 36],
       [26, 21, 41, ..., 36,  0,  8],
       [26, 21, 41, ..., 36,  8,  0]]
    ```
- I have time windows for each vehicle, my desired time window is,

  - For depot (480,540) #8 AM to 9 AM where 480 and 540 are in minutes
  - All other stops time windows are from (540, 960) which is 9AM to 4PM (16:00)
  - ```
       [(480, 540),
        (540, 960),
        (540, 960),
            ...
        (540, 960),
        (540, 960)]
      #1 depot and 3899 parcels
    ```
- The Capacity constraint is that different vehicles can carry in range 140 - 160 parcels.
- Number of vehicles is ceiling(3900/140) where 140 is the number of points i want in one route. For us it will be 28 vehicles.
- I want a 2 minute slack (what my interpretation of slack is, the time driver spends at each location when he reacher there)
- I keep a limit of 60s for it to run also I have kept penalty of 1000 if we want to drop any points.

My current method gives me solution however it does not produce desired output. It produces routes that satisfy the capacity but does not satisfy time; it gives 650 to 900 mins routes (15 hr routes).
Also it is possible to get routes less than 12 hours as I have a solved version data of it.

I do not know where I am going wrong, help would really be appreciated. if you could help at what point I am going wrong. Am I constraining too much and if yes that which one (I wasn't able to figure out i modified and tested many params) ? I will provide the code below this AND I will provide the print_solution output dump in a txt file also if you what to have a deeper look.

[Here is the print dump.](https://pastebin.com/2dDvPphr)

I am not able to attach or paste the 3900 x 3900 matrix but you can make a MRE of like a 100 x 100 on dummy addresses.
To be precise I have random coordinates in this area: https://goo.gl/maps/tGCo5JuADZHb6AyV6

```
from ortools.constraint_solver import routing_enums_pb2
from ortools.constraint_solver import pywrapcp
import random
import math

def create_data_model(distmat):
    """Stores the data for the problem."""
    data = {}
    data['time_matrix'] = distmat
    n = len(distmat)
    time_wd = [(480,540)]
    for i in range(n-1):
        time_wd.append((540,960))
    data['time_windows'] = time_wd
    
    cap_dem = [0] #DEPOT 0
    for i in range(n-1):
        cap_dem.append(1) # ALL OTHERS 1
        
    data['demands'] = cap_dem
    
    max_pack = 160
    min_pack = 140
    data['num_vehicles'] = math.ceil(n/min_pack)
    data['vehicle_capacities'] = sorted(random.choices(range(min_pack, max_pack+1),k=data['num_vehicles']),reverse=True)
    data['depot'] = 0
    return data

def print_solution(data, manager, routing, solution):
    """Prints solution on console."""
    print(f'Objective: {solution.ObjectiveValue()}')
    time_dimension = routing.GetDimensionOrDie('Time')
    total_time = 0
    for vehicle_id in range(data['num_vehicles']):
        index = routing.Start(vehicle_id)
        plan_output = 'Route for vehicle {}:\n'.format(vehicle_id)
        while not routing.IsEnd(index):
            time_var = time_dimension.CumulVar(index)
            plan_output += '{0} Time({1},{2}) -> '.format(
                manager.IndexToNode(index), solution.Min(time_var),
                solution.Max(time_var))
            index = solution.Value(routing.NextVar(index))
        time_var = time_dimension.CumulVar(index)
        plan_output += '{0} Time({1},{2})\n'.format(manager.IndexToNode(index),
                                                    solution.Min(time_var),
                                                    solution.Max(time_var))
        
        plan_output += 'Time of the route: {}min\n'.format(
            solution.Min(time_var))
        print(plan_output)
        total_time += solution.Min(time_var)
    print('Total time of all routes: {}min'.format(total_time))

def maincvrptw(distmat):
    """Solve the VRP with time windows."""
    # Instantiate the data problem.
    data = create_data_model(distmat)
    # Create the routing index manager.
    manager = pywrapcp.RoutingIndexManager(len(data['time_matrix']),
                                           data['num_vehicles'], data['depot'])

    # Create Routing Model.
    routing = pywrapcp.RoutingModel(manager)


    # Create and register a transit callback.
    def time_callback(from_index, to_index):
        """Returns the travel time between the two nodes."""
        # Convert from routing variable Index to time matrix NodeIndex.
        from_node = manager.IndexToNode(from_index)
        to_node = manager.IndexToNode(to_index)
        return data['time_matrix'][from_node][to_node]

    transit_callback_index = routing.RegisterTransitCallback(time_callback)

    # Define cost of each arc.
    routing.SetArcCostEvaluatorOfAllVehicles(transit_callback_index)
    time_t='Time'
    
    # Add Time Windows constraint.
    routing.AddDimension(
        transit_callback_index,
        2,  # 2 MINS WAIT AT EACH LOCATION
        960,  # DRIVERS MAX ROUTE TIME 
        False,  # Don't force start cumul to zero.
        time_t)
    
    time_dimension = routing.GetDimensionOrDie(time_t)
    
    # Add time window constraints for each location except depot.
    for location_idx, time_window in enumerate(data['time_windows']):
        if location_idx == data['depot']:
            continue
        index = manager.NodeToIndex(location_idx)
        time_dimension.CumulVar(index).SetRange(time_window[0], time_window[1])
        
        #PENALTY
        routing.AddDisjunction([manager.NodeToIndex(index)], 1000)
        
    # Add time window constraints for each vehicle start node.
    depot_idx = data['depot']
    for vehicle_id in range(data['num_vehicles']):
        index = routing.Start(vehicle_id)
        time_dimension.CumulVar(index).SetRange(
            data['time_windows'][depot_idx][0],
            data['time_windows'][depot_idx][1])
        
    # Instantiate route start and end times to produce feasible times.
    for i in range(data['num_vehicles']):
        routing.AddVariableMinimizedByFinalizer(
            time_dimension.CumulVar(routing.Start(i)))
        routing.AddVariableMinimizedByFinalizer(
            time_dimension.CumulVar(routing.End(i)))
        

    # Add Capacity constraint.
    def demand_callback(from_index):
        """Returns the demand of the node."""
        # Convert from routing variable Index to demands NodeIndex.
        from_node = manager.IndexToNode(from_index)
        return data['demands'][from_node]
    
    demand_callback_index = routing.RegisterUnaryTransitCallback(demand_callback)
    routing.AddDimensionWithVehicleCapacity(
        demand_callback_index,
        0,  # null capacity slack
        data['vehicle_capacities'],  # vehicle maximum capacities
        False,  # start cumul to zero
        'Capacity')

        
    # Setting first solution heuristic.
    search_parameters = pywrapcp.DefaultRoutingSearchParameters()
    search_parameters.first_solution_strategy = (
        routing_enums_pb2.FirstSolutionStrategy.AUTOMATIC)
    search_parameters.time_limit.FromSeconds(60)

    # Solve the problem.
    solution = routing.SolveWithParameters(search_parameters)

    # Print solution on console.
    if solution:
        print_solution(data, manager, routing, solution)
        print("Done")
    else:
        print("no solution")
    
    return data, manager, routing, solution

data, manager, routing, solution = maincvrptw(distmat)
```

Comment: The time window shows in which time a vehicle should arrive. For your depot, this time is below the ones for your customers. What do you mean by the time window for the depot?